# i can't remove storage in windows azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage

when i remove this detail error

> Blockquote Storage account portalvhdsr3cx7385640s1 has 1 container(s) which have an active image and/or disk artifacts. Ensure those artifacts are removed from the image repository before deleting this storage account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the portal and delete the VHD as well. If you delete the Virtual Macine, only the instance is deleted and VHD will remain in the storage account. Delete the VHD, you will then be able to delete the storage account.